# How to not show specific item in all pages in react.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import Department from "./components/Dept";
import Banner from "./components/Banner";
import Footer from "./components/footer";
import LinksPosition from "./components/NavBar";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  const shouldRedirect = false; // Set your redirect condition here

  if (shouldRedirect) {
    return <Redirect to="/LinksPosition" />;
  }

  // Define the content for Banner and Department components
  const bannerContent = "This is the banner content for all pages";
  const departmentContent = "This is the department content for all pages";

  return (
    <>
      <LinksPosition />

      {/* Render the Banner component with content */}
      <Banner content={bannerContent} />

      {/* Render the Department component with content */}
      <Department content={departmentContent} />

      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Am try to not show the Banner and Department section in all pages after route the link banner and  department are show in pages , i not need to show i need only in homepage

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` are you using, and what pages are you referring to that you want to conditionally render this `Banner` and `Department` component with? Can you [edit] to include a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: how to check version

Comment: From the root project directory you can run command `npm list react-router react-router-dom` and it should output the currently installed versions. You could probably also just look in your package.json file and let us know which you are trying to use.

Comment: 6.15 version are show if u use anydesk can u see my code

Comment: Ah, ok, then the duplicate target is correct. ***But*** RRDv6 hasn't any exported `Redirect` component, that's a v5 export. Import and use `<Navigate to="/LinksPosition" replace />` to replace it.

Comment: replace which line

Comment: I replace it but its show same it is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255156/discussion-between-shivam-pandey-and-drew-reese).